# How to Decode the SAML Token getting From Azure in Java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

1. I have a hosted non-gallery application on Microsoft Azure.
2. I have completed the SAML configuration in Azure AD (using SAML 2.0 protocol)
3. My application runs in Java (runtime 7)
4. I am getting the userPrincipalName as encoded Value.

How do I decode that encoded value and retrieve the actual value?

I have tested the response using SAML Parser, and it is showing the correct value in the `NameID` tag.

I am expecting the value as it is showing in SAML response `NameID` tag, but I am getting an encoded value.

I have tried the following code, but the output is not as expected. I am expecting a string with email format.

[image]

Comment: May I know where you get the SAMLResponse value ? It seems that it is not a common SAMLResponse .

Comment: I am getting this value in <NameID>  tag.Like this:  <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">hEUnPY0HVf5jXb4FoD7BgjZTAoh0RQgyOKnoP5HOhOA=</NameID>. This is Mail Id of user configured at AZURE side.

Comment: It is wired, when I decode SAMLResponse , there is an email ID with out encoded in <NameID> , pls see the capture in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I have appended the capture.

Comment: I am able to decode the whole SAML Response .But NameID value is still Encrypted

Comment: Thanks Stanley, I tried it. the entire SAML repsonse i am able to Decode. But the NameId value i am getting, provided as Encrypted value Only.That Value has been Encrypted using some crypting algorithm.

Comment: @ShraddhaJ Instead of copying a screenshot of the code, please past the actual code itself. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAML tokens are Base64 encoded while transferring . If you are using java 6, just use code below to decode your SAML token:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Base64test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String SAML_resp = "<SAML RESP>";
        byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(SAML_token);
        try {
            System.out.println(new String(decoded, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks For the Help. This Solution requires Java 8. I have my Application on Java 6.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer. Pls mark me if it is helpful : )

Comment: hi, I have updated my Question with your solution, you can see the screenshot. I am not getting the exact decoded String.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that your  NameID Format is "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" , which belongs to transient identifiers. Transient identifiers are what IdP tell the SP that the users in the session have been granted to access the resource on SP, but the identities of users do not offer to SP actually. For example, The assertion just like “Anonymity(Idp doesn’t tell SP who he is) has the permission to access /resource on SP”. SP got it and let browser to access it, but still don’t know Anonymity' real name.

Comment: Btw ,this post explained it well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693297/what-are-the-different-nameid-format-used-for

Comment: Hello @ShraddhaJ , is it helpful for you ?

Comment: Hello @Stanley, yes it is Helpful. It was the issue of NameId format. In Azure (IDP side) it was selected as Persistent. But in Picketlink we are expecting Transient. Now i have set both values at Persistent. It is working Fine.Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0):

Use [OpenSAML 2.x](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home), it'll work with Java 1.6 . Here's an [example](https://github.com/apache/cloudstack/blob/master/plugins/user-authenticators/saml2/src/main/java/org/apache/cloudstack/saml/SAMLUtils.java#L227) that shows parsing and validation of the SAML response via OpenSAML v2