# AWS SSO with Sustainsys/Saml2

Tags: .net-core, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2, aws-sso

While configuring AWS SSO SAML 2.0 application by default it does not include and `NameIdFormat` and if we go with this default metadata for our Service Provider, Sustainsys/Saml2 giving error like below.
Which configuration we can use to make it working without any defined `NameIdFormat` ?

MetaData provided by Identity Provider

**Please note <md:NameIDFormat /> in metadata**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://portal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/saml/assertion/REMOVED_FOR_BREVITY">
   <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
         <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>REMOVED_FOR_BREVITY</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
      </md:KeyDescriptor>
      <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://portal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/saml/logout/REMOVED_FOR_BREVITY" />
      <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://portal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/saml/logout/REMOVED_FOR_BREVITY" />
      <md:NameIDFormat />
      <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://portal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/saml/assertion/REMOVED_FOR_BREVITY" />
      <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://portal.sso.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/saml/assertion/REMOVED_FOR_BREVITY" />
   </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

**Error return by Sustainsys/Saml2**

```
Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializationException: NameIDFormat element with no uri
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializer.ReadNameIDFormat(XmlReader reader)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializer.ReadSsoDescriptorElement(XmlReader reader, SsoDescriptor descriptor)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializer.<>c__DisplayClass119_0.<ReadIdpSsoDescriptor>b__0()
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializer.ReadChildren(XmlReader reader, Func`1 childAction)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializer.ReadIdpSsoDescriptor(XmlReader reader)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializer.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.<ReadEntityDescriptor>b__0()
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializer.ReadChildren(XmlReader reader, Func`1 childAction)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataSerializer.ReadEntityDescriptor(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataLoader.Load(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataLoader.Load(String metadataLocation, IEnumerable`1 signingKeys, Boolean validateCertificate, String minIncomingSigningAlgorithm)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.MetadataLoader.LoadIdp(String metadataLocation, Boolean unpackEntitiesDescriptor)
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.IdentityProvider.DoLoadMetadata()
   at Sustainsys.Saml2.IdentityProvider.set_LoadMetadata(Boolean value)......
```

Comment: The NameIDFormat should have a  URI in the metadata `<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>`. Use unspecified if there is no defined format. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21682789/4018180 for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you it require URI, but this metadata file provided by IDP (Which does not include URI for NameIDFormat)
Any way we can manage and handle at Sustainsys.Saml2 side?

Comment: The source code of `Sustainsys.Saml2` has the validation.  I am not completely sure if the URI can be skipped as per SAML-2.0. You can raise a ticket in github and see if you get any updates. 
https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/20990905ecdcf15f6f76fef80506d53831f7857b/Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata/Serialization/MetadataSerializer.cs.